# POM.XML ISSUE : Project build error resolving expression ${browser.name} Detected the following recursive expression cycle in browser.name

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, pom.xml

I am getting error, which I am not able to resolve

The issue is coming in properties - browser name, because it has ${browser.name} that we are reading the value from the command line.

How can we remove the error?

Tried by removing $ sign, however, we need it to read the value from the command line in maven execution

[image]

Comment: <properties>
  <browser.name>${browser.name}</browser.name>
 </properties>

Answer (score 0):

Can you add here the portion of your pom.xml that is using the ${browser.name} and the actual maven command where you define the value as well?

I could be as simple as invalid maven command and/or how you define the value of ${browser.name}

Answer (score 0):

Try first to define your property with a different name than the same "browser.name", or at least avoid the dot.

```
<properties>
  <browser_name>${browser.name}</browser_name> 
</properties>
```

[Maven properties does mention](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties)

> A dot (`.`) notated path in the POM will contain the corresponding element's value. For example: `<project><version>1.0</version></project>` is accessible via `${project.version}`

That would explain the "recursive expression cycle" error message.